# Can not use position running footer in css

Tags: asp.net, html, css, footer

I have some problem about running page footer. Now I want to set page footer in every page when I'm printing document but I can't use **"position: running"** in ("css") media and in my visual studio already use css3 but it's still like that image, how can I do ? please help. Any suggestion please.

This my code

[image]

Comment: Which browser(s) or layout engines are you using to print this? There seems to be very little support for CSS 3 Paged Media out there.

Comment: printing in chrome browser

Comment: yes. and how can i do ?